# How do I OR a group result in query alter?

Tags: views, database

This is the code that I have made so far.

```
 $query->where[1]['conditions'][]=array(
            'field'=> $payment_field,
            'value' => 16184,
            'operator' => '=',
        );
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
            'field' => $covered_region,
            'value' => $region_id,
            'operator' => '='

        );
 $query->where[1]['conditions'][]=array(
            'field'=> $payment_field,
            'value' => 16185,
            'operator' => '=',
        );
        $query->where[1]['conditions'][] = array(
            'field' => $covered_region,
            'value' => $region_id,
            'operator' => '=',
        );
```

How can I group the following and do as the query below?

```
    AND (
     ((field_data_field_home_care_payment_plan.field_home_care_payment_plan_tid ='16184')AND (field_data_field_covered_regions.field_covered_regions_tid IN  ('65'))) 
OR   ((field_data_field_home_care_payment_plan.field_home_care_payment_plan_tid ='16185')AND (field_data_field_covered_regions.field_covered_regions_tid IN  ('65'))) 
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any particular reason you're manually adding to the where array rather than using the [add_where](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/plugins%21views_plugin_query_default.inc/function/views_plugin_query_default%3A%3Aadd_where/7.x-3.x) function?

I believe you should be able to do something like this:

```
$db_and_1 = db_and()
  ->condition($payment_field, 16184)
  ->condition($covered_region, $region_id);

$db_and_2 = db_and()
  ->condition($payment_field, 16185)
  ->condition($covered_region, $region_id);

$query->add_where(1, db_or()
  ->condition($db_and_1)
  ->condition($db_and_2)
);
```

The important part is the [db_or](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_or/7.x) function.